# CSS selector that applies only to the descendants with closest depth

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have two class HoverShow and HoverHidden.

HoverHidden elements should have at least one HoverShow ancestor and only be displayed when the closest HoverShow ancestor is hovered.

```
.HoverHidden 
{
    display: none;
}

.HoverShow:hover .HoverHidden
{
    display: initial;
}

<div class="HoverShow">
    <div>
        Hover here to see message!
        <div class="HoverHidden">
            message!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above works just fine.

But things get more complicated when HoverHidden has several HoverShow ancestors.

```
<div class="HoverShow">
    <div>
        Hover here to see message!
        <div class="HoverHidden">
            message!
            <div class="HoverShow">
                Now hover here to see another message!
                <div class="HoverHidden">
                    another message!
                    <br />
                    Hey, wait... you shouldn't see that yet!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I adapt my CSS to make it work?

Please note that I have no rule concerning the depth of a HoverHidden under its closest HoverShow ancestor.

Comment: First make your html consistent if possible. Then it will work with @Pranav C Balan's answer below

Comment: @Serge is there any reason why not to use jQuery for this ? (just asking)

Comment: Doing it in CSS makes more sense, it should be more compact and more eassily maintanable. I know this could be done in JQuery but I'd only do that on last resort.

Answer (score 5):

**Your biggest issue with pure css** is your final caveat of "Please note that I have no rule concerning the depth of a HoverHidden under its closest HoverShow ancestor." If it truly could be theoretically infinite, then no pure css solution exists. If there is some reasonable, practical limit for the level of nesting between `HoverShow` and `HoverHidden`, then you could do css like so (this allows up to 3 intermediate levels of nesting, so you can see how impractical this could get with too many more levels):

```
.HoverShow:hover > .HoverHidden,
.HoverShow:hover > :not(.HoverShow) > .HoverHidden,
.HoverShow:hover > :not(.HoverShow) > :not(.HoverShow) > .HoverHidden,
.HoverShow:hover > :not(.HoverShow) > :not(.HoverShow) > :not(.HoverShow) > .HoverHidden
{
    display: initial;
}
```

[**See a fiddle example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tj7Z7/2/)

**Please Note**

A simple descendent `.HoverShow:hover :not(.HoverShow) .HoverHidden` will not work, as it will have positive hits on *any* descendent element that has no `.HoverShow` class, so as [this fiddle shows](http://jsfiddle.net/Tj7Z7/3/), the *third* group *does* show on the hover of the *second* group because of the intervening nesting creating elements that do "not" have the `.HoverShow` class on them.

Answer (score 0):

Use `>` , it only looks one level down the markup structure, no deeper.

```
.HoverShow:hover>.HoverHidden
{
    display: initial;
}
```

In order to work this, you need to make a slight change in your markup

```
<div class="HoverShow">
    Hover here to see message!
    <div class="HoverHidden">
        message!
        <div class="HoverShow">
            Now hover here to see another message!
            <div class="HoverHidden">
                another message!
                <br />
                Hey, wait... you shouldn't see that yet!
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/YLPhg/2/)

Or you can try without changing the markup as follows

```
.HoverShow:hover >div>.HoverHidden,.HoverShow:hover >.HoverHidden
{
    display: initial;
}
.HoverHidden
{
    display: none;
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/YLPhg/3/)

Comment: it can't work for the first level with the given markup

Comment: the problem is that the question specify *"I have no rule concerning the depth of a HoverHidden under its closest HoverShow ancestor."* so this approach works if and only if you have no other wrappers in the middle

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with the direct descendant selector:

```
.HoverHidden 
{
    display: none;
}

.HoverShow:hover > .HoverHidden{
    display: initial;
}
```

**WORKING** Example with your original HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/8enBe/

**WORKING** Example with a deeper structure: http://jsfiddle.net/Eu93U/

## important:

Do get this work, you need to keep the structure like

```
<div class="HoverShow">
    <!-- next .HoverHidden descendant of this MUST BE a DIRECT descendant -->
    <div class="HoverHidden">
        <!-- next .HoverShow descendant of this MUST BE a DIRECT descendant -->
    </div>    
</div>
```

If you don't keep this structure, it won't work :)

Hope that helped.